# Using jQuery to parse a JSONP where source uses a variable instead of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, c3.js

I am trying to parse some data from a source that is formatted like this:

```
var = jsonReturnData = {}
```

instead of this:

```
jsonReturnData({})
```

If I read the file using a script tag like this:

```
<script src="http://foundationphp.com/phpclinic/podata.php?startDate=20150301&endDate=20150302&raw"></script>
```

I have no problem reading the data, but if I try to do any sort of JSON or JSONP call from within jQuery, I either get an error or no access to the data depending on how I do it.

```
$.getJSON('http://foundationphp.com/phpclinic/podata.php?startDate=20150301&endDate=20150321&raw', function(data) {
  console.log(jsonReturnData);
});
```

I need to be able to load the data dynamically when someone chooses some dates. Here's a sample of the interface working, but with no access to the JSON file. The data that you see is being read by the script method.

http://iviewsource.com/exercises/codeclinic/01/

Comment: Ditch jQuery and do the JSONP request yourself. You just don't need jQuery for that.

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't work. Anyways I'm using bootstrap, so jQuery is already loaded.

Comment: Did you add an `onload` event handler to the script? `var s = createElement("script"); s.src = "http://example.com"; s.onload = function() { console.log(window.jsonReturnData); }; document.body.appendChild(s);`

Comment: ...in any case, with jQuery, try using a `complete` callback instead of `success`. That one should fire no matter what. You'll then be able to access the `window.jsonReturnData`.

Comment: [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is not parsed, it's executed